# Is it possible to host a website on a computer but use the static IP from a vpn-server on a google cloud vm?

Tags: apache, web, web-hosting, self-hosting

I have my website up and running on a google cloud vm. But it runs slow because i only use the cheapest one. Before upgrading the vm to a more powerful one, is it possible to host a website on my own computer using the IP from google cloud vm? I successfully set up a vpn server on it using softether (checking whatsmyip on my computer shows the public IP from google cloud vm). Any tips and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

VPN is usually for outgoing connections, not incoming. Generally speaking, you would need to have some kind of thin server running on your cloud instance, that forwards all incoming connections to your home machine. From visitors' perspective they will be connecting to the cloud IP, but all the work will be done by your home PC.

Of course your home PC will probably have a dynamic IP so it will have to keep the server updated on this.

Here is one very simple implementation. Do not actually do this, it is just an illustration:

1. Run your website on your home PC so that it serves on eg. `localhost:8000`
2. Set up an SSH server on your home PC
3. SSH into cloud PC
4. From there, SSH *back* into your home PC with SSH forwarding of `localhost:8000`
5. Run the reverse proxy (eg. nginx) on your cloud PC and tell it to proxy to `localhost:8000`

Requests will be proxied to your home PC through SSH so long as the connection is alive. This is obviously not a convenient setup and letting a cloud machine SSH into your home PC is a bad idea for many reasons. You could try to restrict the SSH into your home PC, or even run a VPN *server* at home and have your cloud instance connect to that VPN to access the website. However that is still not a best practices way to do it.

A better way would be:

1. Obtain a stable URL (doesn't have to be a full domain, just something that can forward to you IP)
2. Run an nginx reverse proxy on your cloud server, and tell it to proxy to this URL
3. Ensure the URL points to your home PC when you IP changes (ideally you want an "update IP" script that runs everytime you turn on your home PC)

If you don't want a URL, you could also write a simple script to update a `hosts` entry on the remote machine with your home PC's IP.